# Angular2 Directive change inner content breaks bindings

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Im trying to create a directive that will replace the text inside it something else. I tried several approaches and i have been able to change the text of the element, however when i change the text my bindings stop working.

Here is an example

```
<div *replaceText >Lets replace every word that is ':text:' {{modelValue}}</div>
```

So i want to replace every word ':text:' with ':replaced:'. That i can do by getting the element and changing the innerText of the HTMLElement, however this will break my {{modelValue}} binding and what i would like to do is also change any ':text:' that is inside the 'modelValue' variable.

Anyone have some idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I don't think that is supposed to work.

Comment: why don't you just put the text into a controller variable? Simple `{{currentText}} {{modelValue}}` should do the job. Then replace the things inside of controller to whatever you want.